# Metro app Holding event in games

Tags: c#, events, microsoft-metro, 2d-games

I made a game where user navigates a character. Since it is designed for both PC and tablet (with Win8), there are two options how to do it.

1) using keyboard (`Key_Down` and `Key_Up` events)

2) using touch and hold (`Tapped` and `Holding` events)

Unfortunately there is a problem with `Holding` event, because it raises after a *long* time period (I think 1 sec). I had to use word *long* there becase it really is a long time period in games.

Now, I need a better solution. There is a onscreen joystick in the game compounded from four images that stands for arrows. **How do I make player's character move immediately and continuously just by tap-and-hold on the arrow image?**

Comment: I'am using javascript for metro app dev and there I'am using MSPointerDown/MSPointerUp for nearly the same. Maybe it is simlar in c#? Can this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150606.aspx) help?

Comment: And can you still recognize if it was tapped or is being holded?

Comment: Don't know if i get your question right. But I'am using the MsPointer-eventhandler to move a usercontrol  (hold and moved around). I'am using MSPointerDown to regonize the first tap, MSPointerMove to move the user-control (similar to your holding) and MSPointerUp to release the handler. [Here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673464/how-do-i-detect-multitouch-actions-in-a-windows-8-metro-app/11176986#11176986) you can find an JS example (bit messy, but it works). [Here](http://www.janhommes.de/canvascurve/) you can see pictures of my control in action.

Comment: I finally implemented events you suggested me and it works as I hoped it will. Make answer from your first comment so that I can mark it as the Answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am using javascript for metro app dev and there I'am using MSPointerDown/MSPointerUp for nearly the same. Maybe it is simlar in c#? Can this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150606.aspx) help?